# Write URL's in HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I've used Python's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to extract URL's from a webpage. Now, I want to write these URL's into an HTML Document using Python. So if I had www.ex1.com, www.ex2.com and so on, I want to use python to create an HTML document which will have the following:

```
<a href='www.ex1.com'>Something</a>
<a herf='www.ex2.com'>Something else</a>
```

Are there any python modules which will help me with this?

Edit- I don't want to only generate the URL's. I'd like to do so while being able to put them in a table/ edit their titles etc.

Comment: If all you're doing is creating a series of links, that's easy enough to do with just `write()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: html writer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612069/python-html-writer)

Comment: Is your question silly or are we missing something? let me brief it.
`<a href='URL'>Something</a>` you are just inserting URL value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an html table of links that contain HTML you should look into using the Jinja2 library (or one of the other templating modules).

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

You could create a `dict` of URL's and pass it to a Jinja template and have a `for` loop add them all to the page.